# Reading list entries in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, header, dataframe

I have got a list with 12 entries.

```
[[1]]
     event_id   time_occurred        
[1,] "MX050113" "2013-03-29 05:45:03"
[2,] "MX050112" "2013-03-29 05:43:03"
[3,] "MX050113" "2013-03-29 05:42:03"
[4,] "MX050110" "2013-03-29 05:41:03"
[5,] "MX050513" "2013-03-29 05:39:03"
[6,] "MX050113" "2013-03-29 05:38:03"`

[[2]]
      event_id   time_occurred        
[1,] "MX050117" "2013-03-29 06:47:03"
[2,] "MX050122" "2013-03-29 06:44:03"
[3,] "MX050213" "2013-03-29 06:42:03"
[4,] "MX050160" "2013-03-29 06:40:03"
[5,] "MX020513" "2013-03-29 06:38:03"`

[[3]]
  .
  .
  .
[[12]]
```

Now in [[1]]..[[12]], how to read data under header == time_occurred for position [1,2] in [[1]]?
I can't give you the R code for this list so please suggest me the syntax for my query.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bunch of matrices, and you want to extract the second column in each. So use `lapply`:

```
lapply(lst, function(x) x[, 2])
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I calculate number of rows of a matrix at [[1]]? `nrow` is not working while `length` is giving me 1 which is not correct. Its urgent please help me if you the way. Thank you